# Negative association in correlation and regression

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation

If my research study is about a negative association between risk and performance, it is expected that my pearson's correlation analysis will be negatively correlated, and the beta coefficients will be negative, and the R-square is also negative. am i right?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance?"

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck

Comment: what i meant by Performance is Project performance, its the depedent variable in my study

Comment: @gung my research study is about risk and how it impacts the project performance. however my study is so far significant, but the correlation analysis is positive, instead of negatively correlated. beta is also in positive, and R-square is positive. I am trying to find, these values are suppose to be negative in a negative associated study. Or maybe i am missing something. my next question is, do i have to transform my data into negative? my questionnaire is based on 5-point likert scale, if yes, do i have to transform both independent and dependent variables?

Comment: Just because the result was surprising doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: You're going to have to say more about why you think you need to do anything. What it sounds like you are saying it this: "I expected negative correlation but got positive correlation. How do I make it negative?" If you doubt the positive correlation then you should be looking into the correlation analysis rather than trying to figure out how to transform the result of that analysis.

Comment: @WillieWheeler no, that is not what i am saying. im not transforming the data like that. My results are significant, but with a positive correlation, where as in most cases negative associated study such as risk are mostly showing negative correlation instead of positive correlation. i am guessing that i may have not input the data correctly in SPSS. if i am working on negative association between dependent and independent variable, do i have to transform my data first?

Comment: There seems to be quite a big difference between what the question is asking, and what additional information and requests there are in the comments section. Can you edit your question so that it's clear what you're hoping to learn from an answer?

Comment: Why is this question on hold? At the time it was closed, there was an answer that had been accepted and the OP had said that it's helpful. Therefore, it was easy to see what was asked, and I can assure you that I didn't use any kind of mind-reading ability. It was just that the question was clear enough to tell what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have observations with pairs of values risk and performance, and that you expect to get lower numerical values of performance for higher numerical values of risk.

If that trend is true, you should get:

- Positive r-squared (between 0 and 1) because r-squared is always positive. In fact, with just one predictor r-squared is the square of correlation, and therefore positive.
- Negative correlation.
- Negative beta (that is, negative slope of regression line).

Beware that if you have more than one predictor, parameters (beta coefficients) can show some counter-intuitive behaviour, specially if predictors are correlated.

Anyway, I would suggest to plot an scatterplot of your data to see if there is a clear trend. It could also help to identify an error when introducing data.